# How does the effective focal length work for aspheric lenses? How should I select an aspheric lens?

Tags: optics, laser, geometric-optics, lenses, interferometry

I am currently looking at [aspheric lenses on Thorlabs](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=3811). I want to use them as a collimation optic for my interferometry experiment. Note that the lenses have a listed EFL (effective focal length). But then this made me think: if the beam is [collimated, and so the light rays are parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collimated_beam), then how does it even make sense to have an "effective focal length", since parallel light rays don't come to a [focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length) (that is, meet/intersect at a point) – [even in a virtual way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_image) (at least, as I understand it)? So I'm confused as to how I should select for aspheric lenses for my experiment.

Comment: Are you trying to collimate a laser beam originating out of a fiber optic cable?

Comment: @jamie1989 no, directly from a laser diode.

Comment: So are you making a laser for your experiment? Are you trying to manipulate a beam that is currently divergent or is already collimated from a functional laser?

Comment: @jamie1989 I'm not trying to build a laser – I'll be buying/using an off-the-shelf laser diode. But the beam is obviously going to be divergent, so I want to put the diode in a mount with an aspheric lens to collimate the beam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of your laser source will have some divergence, if you place a [plano-convex spherical lens](https://www.thorlabs.com/navigation.cfm?guide_id=100) at a displacement equal to the focal length, then the emerging beam will be collimated. Such that, the origin of the beam becomes the focal point of a collimated source in the reverse direction.

The size of the beam depends on the angle of divergence and the focal length. A good website to find out some common beam dimensions from optical components is Edmund Optics' [knowledge centre](https://www.edmundoptics.co.uk/knowledge-center/#!&CategoryId=199).

Comment: But how does this address my question?

Comment: @ThePointer The origin of the beam becomes the focal point of a collimated source in the reverse direction.

Comment: Ohh, yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: So if the EFL of the aspheric lens is 1.5mm, then the aspheric lens should be placed 1.5mm in front of the laser source point (in this case, the laser diode emitting chip) in order to produce a collimated beam?

Comment: Yes. But for a coherent source of light you need a few more elements than just a diode and a lens.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by "a few more elements"? Please elaborate.

Comment: A diode alone does not emit coherent light. It might be worth researching something like an external cavity diode laser (ECDL) if your end goal is to produce a coherent source of collimated light.

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm aware of this. Thanks!

Comment: @jamie1989 it does, otherwise one wouldn't observe [speckle pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_speckle) in such light. Granted, coherence length is not as large as in other types of lasers, but it's still much larger than in a LED output, for example.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, I think he was referring to coherence length (linewidth, etc.). I have indeed researched such matters.